# React native drag and drop between flatlist

Tags: react-native

I have two flatlist consist of 5 and 10 items, i want to drag 1 item from first flatlist to second and vice verse , i have searched for many library but havent found any one yet.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this blog helps

[React native : Drag and drop between two lists](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/drag-drop-and-swap-between-two-lists-using-react-native-d864dab43aa9)

Comment: In this blog we can only swap elements from 2nd list to first , you cannot send elemnt from 1st to second. I want to modify the element from both list.

Comment: both are 'DraxView' component right? So I think you can customize it by adding 'onReceiveDragDrop' props in both. Just try it.

Comment: Ya it's mentioned at last of the blog itself : "This implementation is simple but you can build on top of it to make your drag drop and **swap between lists** more dynamic and feature rich."

Answer (score -2):

You can easily achieve this thing with [react-native-draggable-flatlist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist)

```
import DraggableFlatList, {
  ScaleDecorator,
} from "react-native-draggable-flatlist";

<DraggableFlatList
      data={data}
      onDragEnd={({ data }) => setData(data)}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
```

Hope it will you!

Comment: you cannot do this with library , we can only drag and drop inside single list